# Finding $P(X_1 < X_2 < X_3)$: Explanation of last part of solution

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I have the following problem:

> Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be independent $\text{Geom}(p_1)$, $\text{Geom}(p_2)$, $\text{Geom}(p_3)$ random variables respectively.
>
> Find $P(X_1 < X_2 < X_3)$.

The solution is as follows:

> $$\begin{align} P(X_1 < X_2 < X_3) &= \sum_{i_1 = 0}^\infty P(X_1 < X_2 < X_3 | X_1 = i_1) P(X_1 = i_1) \\ &= \sum_{i_1 = 0}^\infty P(i_1 < X_2 < X_3 | X_1 = i_1) P(X_1 = i_1) \\ &= \sum_{i_2 = 0}^\infty \sum_{i_1 = 0}^\infty P(i_1 + i_2 + 1 < X_3) P(X_2 = i_1 + i_2 + 1) P(X_1 = i_1) \\ &= \sum_{i_3 = 0}^\infty \sum_{i_2 = 0}^\infty \sum_{i_1 = 0}^\infty P(X_3 = i_1 + i_2 + i_3 + 2) P(X_2 = i_1 + i_2 + 1) P(X_1 = i_1) \\ &= \sum_{i_3 = 0}^\infty \sum_{i_2 = 0}^\infty \sum_{i_1 = 0}^\infty q_3^{i_1 + i_2 + i_3 + 2} p_3 q_2^{i_1 + i_2 + 1} p_2 q_1^{i_1} p_1 \\ &= p_1 p_2 p_3 q_2 q_3^2 \sum_{i_3 = 0}^\infty \sum_{i_2 = 0}^\infty \sum_{i_1 = 0}^\infty q_3^{i_3} (q_2 q_3)^{i_2} (q_1 q_2 q_3)^{i_1} \\ &= \dfrac{p_1 p_2 p_3 q_2 q_3^2}{(1 - q_3)(1 - q_2 q_3)(1 - q_1 q_2 q_3)} \end{align}$$

I'm unsure of how the author got $p_1 p_2 p_3 q_2 q_3^2 \sum_{i_3 = 0}^\infty \sum_{i_2 = 0}^\infty \sum_{i_1 = 0}^\infty q_3^{i_3} (q_2 q_3)^{i_2} (q_1 q_2 q_3)^{i_1} = \dfrac{p_1 p_2 p_3 q_2 q_3^2}{(1 - q_3)(1 - q_2 q_3)(1 - q_1 q_2 q_3)}$? I would greatly appreciate it if someone could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general $$\sum_i\sum_j\sum_k a^ib^jc^k=\sum_ia^i(\sum_j\sum_k b^jc^k)=(\sum_j\sum_k b^jc^k)\sum_ia_i$$and:$$\sum_j\sum_k b^jc^k=\sum_jb_j(\sum_k c^k)=(\sum_k c^k)\sum_jb_j$$Applying that we end up with: $$\sum_i\sum_j\sum_k a^ib^jc^k=(\sum_ia^i)(\sum_jb^j)(\sum_kc^k)$$

If $i,j,k$ start at $0$ then this equals: $$\frac1{1-a}\frac1{1-b}\frac1{1-c}$$

Comment: Oeps I made mistake. It is repaired now and will make things clear.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it valid to say that $\sum_{i_1 = 0}^\infty P(i_1 < X_2 < X_3 | X_1 = i_1) P(X_1 = i_1) = \sum_{i_1 = 0}^\infty P(i_1 < X_2 < X_3) P(X_1 = i_1)$, since $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are independent, instead of $\sum_{i_1 = 0}^\infty P(i_1 < X_2 < X_3 | X_1 = i_1) P(X_1 = i_1) = \sum_{i_1 = 0}^\infty P(i_1 < X_2 < X_3 | X_1 = i_1) P(X_1 = i_1)$?

Comment: ^ I just checked and it is.